# How to create a row with 9 columns without the data getting overflown using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I created a row with 9 columns with my custom CSS by giving each column a width of 11.11% which makes 9 equal columns.

Now I applied this custom-column class to the data in a row :

```css
.custom-column {
  width: 11.11%!important;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>First Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Second Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Third Column(Text is getting extended)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Fourth Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Fifth Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Sixth Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Seventh Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Eigth Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Ninth Column</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is good if the text within each column is a simple small word. But if there is a large text the text in a column is getting overlapped on the other column's text.

The text in my columns varies every time. I'm trying to get the text from the server so sometimes I may get large texts.

How should I deal with it?

Is there a way I can handle 9 equal columns even if the text gets bigger? or else Is there any other alternate way to do this?

I even searched about this issue, but couldn't get the exact results.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add `word-wrap: break-word` and some `padding`

```css
.custom-column {
  width: 11.11%;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>First Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Second Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Third Column(Text is getting extended)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Fourth Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Fifth Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Sixth Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Seventh Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Eigth Column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Ninth Column</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: You can check the snippet for the result

Answer (score 2):

Just use following CSS to resolve this issue

```
.custom-column {
    float: left;
    width: 11.11% !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a responsive table instead. Hope this solves your problem.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <td>First Column</td>
              <td>Second Column</td>
              <td>Third Column (Text is getting extended)</td>
              <td>Fourth Column</td>
              <td>Fifth Column</td>
              <td>Sixth Column</td>
              <td>Seventh Column</td>
              <td>Eigth Column</td>
              <td>Ninth Column</td>
           </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: But there is a horizontal scroll bar with this table. I don't want that.

Comment: I have made some changes.. Try it in a full page. You won't get that scroll bar. Long words won't get clipped too.

Answer (score -2):

This is the best way use custom css:

```css
.custom-row {
margin-right: -2px;
margin-left: -2px;
}
.custom-column {
width: 11.11111111%;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-left: 2px;
float:left;
word-wrap: break-word;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-row">
    <div class="custom-column">
      <p>First Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Second Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Third Column(Text is getting extended)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Fourth Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Fifth Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Sixth Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Seventh Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Eigth Column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-column">
    <p>Ninth Column</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But I want my columns to be aligned horizontally not vertically.

Comment: Ninth column is not on the same line bro @Awadesh Varma

Comment: Hey Nitin, You have used bootstrap css so use this code. this is working correctly

Comment: @Awadheshverma What is the connection between the `bootstrap.css` and your code? I don't see any class from Bootstrap being used

Comment: box-sizing define globally in bootstrap and box-sizing is resize content-box